# Diode doesn't work in a [attempt of] power supply simulation with QUCS

Tags: qucs

As a simulation exercise, I am trying to work out a power supply and actually I am at the point provided in the figure below

[image]

There is a message of error which I don't understand, but I realized it happens only with the presence of the diode in the circuit.

In fact, in order to understand this, I did two other attempts: a separate circuit on the right with a diode which works fine and a short circuit around the diode itself which is reported in the next figure

[image]

and still it works fine.

So the question is:
which is the problem with adding that diode in the circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a warning message relating to the fact that you have the secondary of Tr1 (the transformer) floating. It would be better to ground one side for the purposes of simulation.

I don't see an error message.

Comment: it works! Still I don't understand the reason for which if no diodes is present than it could work even without a ground attached at the secondary coil, while the ground became necessary once one diode is present there...